# Reset button for different radio groups in HTML

Tags: html, jsp, web, radio-button, jstl

I have HTML form with several radion button groups,which are created dynamically in JSP.
In runtime I don't know the number of radiobuttons and groups. I have to create reset button for each radio button group. Now I have a button that clears all radios in form. 
And I cannot do different forms for different radiogroups.

Answer (score 1):

Include a normal radio button, with a normal label, indicating a “no selection” option, into each group. It will then act as a “reset button” for the group in a natural way. Example:

```
<fieldset><legend>Sex</legend>
<div><input type=radio id=female name=sex value=2>
  <label for=female>Female</label></div>
<div><input type=radio id=male name=sex value=1>
  <label for=male>Male</label></div>
<div><input type=radio id=no name=sex value=0>
  <label for=no>Not disclosed</label></div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function resetSex() {
      for(var el = document.getElementsByName('sex'), i = el.length; i--;)
        el[i].checked=false;
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset><legend>Sex</legend>
<div><input type=radio id=female name=sex value=2>
  <label for=female>Female</label></div>
<div><input type=radio id=male name=sex value=1>
  <label for=male>Male</label></div>
<div><button onclick="resetSex()">Reset</div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```